# Arduino Serial.available() keeps increasing

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using an [Arduino Uno R3](https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/uno-rev3) and when I send an AT command to my [GSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM) shield via Serial, I get an increasing number from Serial.available().

Here is the example I have been using to debug:

```
void loop()
{
    Serial.println("AT+CADC?");
    delay(3000);
}

void serialEvent()
{
  char * sensorValue;
  int serial = Serial.available();
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print(serial);
  Serial.println("-");
  if(serial >0)
  {
    sensorValue = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (serial +1));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < serial; i++)
    {
      sensorValue[i] = Serial.read();
      //Serial.print(sensorValue[i]);
    }
    sensorValue[serial+1] = '\0';
    Serial.print(sensorValue);
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

The result I get from the serial monitor is:

> -30-
>
> -63-
>
> -63-
>
> -63-
>
> ...

Why does the number of bytes available start off at 30 and then max out at 63? This happens even when I use Serial.read(), which should consume the data in the buffer.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show any reads so the result is expected.  It counts the bytes from the modem response.

Comment: Well like I mentioned towards the end the result is the same even with reads. I just edited the code to show my full code where I do reads.

Comment: It isn't the problem here, but note that serialEvent() is ***line-oriented*** (not very clear in the documentation, absent in the code comments, and misleading in the example code). That is, a newline (whatever that is. ASCII 13?) is required before serialEvent is called. The canonical is *[Arduino "SerialEvent" example code doesn't work on my Arduino Nano. I can't receive serial data. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013619/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sensorValue[serial+1] = '\0';
Serial.print(sensorValue);      // <== here
```

You send whatever you receive right back to the modem.  Which promptly echoes it back.  So once you got it going with an AT command, you'll forever loop sending the same bytes back and forth.  Remove the Serial.print() calls.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense, though I'm looking to get the response from the modem and see it in the terminal. How can I get the result without kicking it into a loop?

Comment: I don't know enough about your specific Arduino hardware and firmware, that's a moving target.  But clearly your code needs to distinguish between *two* serial ports.  One for the modem, the other for the terminal.  No idea how that could work when you only have "Serial", sorry.  The vendor's forum is a good place to find people that tinker with custom hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use the software serial library—[SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial)—and use that to access the GSM modem, unless the GSM modem requires [UART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter) or [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) level signals.

Another alternative, which might be appropriate if most of your work involves talking to modems, would be an [Arduino Mega 2560](https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/mega-2560).  It has four hardware serial interfaces, though it doesn't have RS-232 output signals.  For that, you should be able to use one of the [FTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI) breakout boards.

Comment: Good suggestion on the Mega 2560, I might have to look into it. I'm at a prototyping and only got the UNO R3 since it was the latest model.