# Arduino "SerialEvent" example code doesn't work on my Arduino Nano. I can't receive serial data. Why?

Tags: arduino

I am following the tutorial *[SerialEvent](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialEvent)* and am trying this code:

However, when I send my [Arduino Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Official) serial data, it does not seem to be received. When I send it a message over serial, it should print it back out to the Arduino Serial Monitor (serial console), but it doesn't. Why? What am I doing wrong?

More details:

I need communication from my PC to the Arduino in real-time. Therefore, I cannot use `delay()` in my Arduino loop. The project consists of sending a message from a computer *to* the Arduino and receiving and parsing it in the Arduino. This example code seems perfect since it does not use the `delay()` function. Unfortunately, it does not work. I send a text string from my computer to the Arduino over serial and the Arduino does not print anything to the serial monitor. My Arduino is the Nano ATmega328.

Also, I don't see this example code calling the `serialEvent()` function anywhere. Where do I have to call `serialEvent()`? Or, how does it otherwise ever run and get called?

Here is the code, copy-pasted from the example above:

```cpp
String inputString = "";         // A string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // Whether the string is complete

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Reserve 200 bytes for the inputString:
  inputString.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
  // Print the string when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {
    Serial.println(inputString);

    // Clear the string:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the
  hardware serial RX.  This routine is run between each
  time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can delay
  response.  Multiple bytes of data may be available.
 */
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {

    // Get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();

    // Add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;

    // If the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to improve your title and description of the problem. Describe: what you did, what happened, what you expected to happen. For the title, make it describe the error or problem or goal instead of being a generic statement that could apply to almost anything.

Comment: Looks like you blatantly copied your entire code in the question from here (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialEvent) without citing that source, mentioning that, or providing the link. Therefore, I have downvoted your question. Please cite all sources in the future.

Comment: Of course is a original code from arduino, that was i explain before, i found that problem executing when i use the original code, but i found the solution while i was waiting answers, thats why i post the answer, it can be helpfull. I not apologize to provide support. How much persons has passed by this same problem?, why more have to pass?

Comment: Arduino, it is a registered trademark, I cannot use this name without legal authorization, except when requesting help from official and unofficial sources. [Read Trademark Information](https://www.arduino.cc/en/trademark)

Comment: "Of course is a original code from arduino, that was i explain before". ITDuino, no, you didn't explain that at all. Nonetheless, I know what it's like to be new, and I will help you by editing this question and answer to be useful for the next person. The only reason I asked for you to improve the question was because _I didn't understand it._ I know a lot about Arduino, and genuinely wanted to help you, _but I didn't know how because I couldn't figure out what you were asking._ Also, it won't help the next person if you don't have a clear question, so again, I will edit them to help.

Comment: Done. This question and answer is now a canonical answer, in my opinion, on how to use `serialEvent()` on Arduino, for all to reference in the future.

Comment: The RTFM here is absolutely not warranted. The documentation is poorly written, the comments in the standard code example does not mention it, and the code example is misleading. Most readers will not register that serialEvent() is ***** line-oriented ******.

Comment: The RTFM here is way overstated. The newline requirement is both *unexpected* and easily overlooked. *For instance*, the call back function is badly named. It should be "LineReceivedSerialEvent" or something like that to indicate it doesn't work on single characters, only lines. Contributing to it is the use of reading a single character in the example code "char inChar = (char)Serial.read();" and that the comments to the serialEvent() function does not mentioned that it is line-oriented, not character orientend.

Answer (score 3):

### You need a `\n` at the end of any string you send over serial TO the Arduino:

Notice this part of the `serialEvent()` function:

```cpp
// if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
// so the main loop can do something about it:
if (inChar == '\n') {
stringComplete = true;
}
```

As you can see, it is looking for the `\n` (newline) character to indicate the full string has been received. So, you *must* include a newline (`\n`) at the end of the string you are sending to the Arduino.

The tutorial (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialEvent) also states (emphasis added):

> This example demonstrates use of the `serialEvent()` function. This function is automatically called at the end of `loop()` when there is serial data available in the buffer. In this case, each character found is added to a string **until a newline is found**. Then the string is printed and set back to null.

If using the Arduino Serial Monitor, be sure to choose the "Newline" option from the dropdown at the bottom. Then, whenever you type something in the bar at the top and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will automatically append a `\n` to the end of your string to the Arduino when you send it. [image]

If sending data from a C, C++, Python, Java, or other program to the Arduino over serial, again, be sure to include a `\n` at the end of your string TO the Arduino.

### How does `serialEvent()` get called anyway?

To answer this:

> Also, I don't see this example code calling the `serialEvent()` function anywhere. Where do I have to call `serialEvent()`? Or, how does it otherwise ever run and get called?

In short, the fact that you defined the `serialEvent()` function *at all* makes it get called automatically by the Arduino core code. If you don't define it, it won't get called. If you do define it, it will. This is because your definition of `serialEvent()` is strong and overrides the `weak` one [declared here in HardwareSerial.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L45):

```cpp
// SerialEvent functions are weak, so when the user doesn't define them,
// the linker just sets their address to 0 (which is checked below).
// The Serialx_available is just a wrapper around Serialx.available(),
// but we can refer to it weakly so we don't pull in the entire
// HardwareSerial instance if the user doesn't also refer to it.
#if defined(HAVE_HWSERIAL0)
  void serialEvent() __attribute__((weak)); // <======
  bool Serial0_available() __attribute__((weak));
#endif
```

So, if you define a `serialEvent()` function at all, that makes the address to that function non-zero (whereas if it was simply the gcc `weak` declaration, it would remain zero), making this `if` statement true, so `serialEvent()` gets called [inside the `serialEventRun()` function:](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L67)

```cpp
void serialEventRun(void)
{
#if defined(HAVE_HWSERIAL0)
  if (Serial0_available && serialEvent && Serial0_available()) serialEvent();
  // ...
#endif
}
```

And, that in-turn gets called [in the Arduino `main()` function here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L47):

```cpp
for (;;) {
    loop();
    if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
}
```

So, let's go over that again. If you do NOT define `serialEvent()`, then its only declaration is this:

```cpp
void serialEvent() __attribute__((weak));
```

That's a weak declaration, so it will simply give the function a program space memory address of `0` (zero) in the event it is never defined. That means that this `if` statement is false, so `serialEvent()` is never called inside `serialEventRun()`:

```cpp
if (Serial0_available && serialEvent && Serial0_available()) serialEvent();
```

If that's the case, then `serialEventRun()` contains nothing and apparently is also given a program space address of `0` (zero) since it has nothing to do. That makes this `if` statement in the `main()` function false, and `serialEventRun()` never gets called either:

```cpp
for (;;) {
    loop();
    if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
}
```

### Don't use `serialEvent()` at all

Personally, I don't think you should use `serialEvent` at all. Just add the logic to the `loop()` function directly, like this. You get the exact same effect and get to control things manually yourself instead. Notice that the *only* changes I made were:

1. I renamed the `serialEvent()` function to `readSerial()`.
2. I added the `readSerial()` call to the top of your `loop()` function.

That's it! Here is the code with those changes. I tested it on an ATmega328-based Pro Mini just now and it works fine, properly printing out any newline (`\n`)-terminated string I send to it, same as the unmodified code for this example as well.

```cpp
String inputString = "";         // a String to hold incoming data
bool stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete

void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // reserve 200 bytes for the inputString:
  inputString.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
  readSerial();
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {
    Serial.println(inputString);
    // clear the string:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

void readSerial() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
    // do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Why did they make the weak `serialEvent()` function at all when that's all you need to do to control this manually as it is? I don't know. It's probably a convenience thing: it saves you a few lines of code if you are doing this (overriding `weak` function calls) for multiple serial event calls, such as `serialEvent()`, `serialEvent1()`, `serialEvent2()`, and `serialEvent3()`. For more-obvious control, however, I'd just manually make my own functions and call them inside the `loop()` function instead, as I do just above.

### Other References:

1. gcc `weak` function attribute: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html (the most-recent gcc documentation on this is now here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-weak-function-attribute):

   > weak
   >
   > The `weak` attribute causes the declaration to be emitted as a weak symbol rather than a global. This is primarily useful in defining library functions which can be overridden in user code, though it can also be used with non-function declarations. Weak symbols are supported for ELF targets, and also for a.out targets when using the GNU assembler and linker.
2. From my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo, here is my [check_addr_of_weak_undefined_funcs.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/check_addr_of_weak_undefined_funcs.cpp) file where I prove to myself that `weak` functions which are declared but not defined really do have addresses equal to nil (ie: zero, or `0`).

Answer (score 1):

I found the basic problem is in the function you may have on your PC which publishes data over serial to the Arduino. It is NOT in the `serialEvent()` function on the Arduino which receives that data. The problem is that when you send a message by serial to the Arduino, you have to include a newline (`\n` char), so that the end-of-message detection on the Arduino in the `serialEvent()` function works.

Examples in different programming languages:

**Sending message to the Arduino from your PC by C:**

```
String Message = "Hello world.\n";
```

**Sending message to the Arduino from your PC by C#:**

```
string Message = "Hello world." + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

**Sending message to the Arduino from your PC by JavaScript via nwjs:**

```
var Message = "Hello world.\n";
```

**Sending message to the Arduino from your PC by Python:**

```
Message = "Hello world.\n";

# OR

Message = """Hello world.
""";
```

*The situation is similar in other programming languages.*